# What's the best source/way of learning geometry nodes? (Except of the basics)

Tags: geometry-nodes, documentation

**This question could be marked as opinion based or off-topic, but to be honest, there are few places to ask this. There's [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15355/resources-for-blender) question which could be an answer, but I feel it's too related to documentation to answer my question.**

Long story:

Since the release of geometry nodes, there has been a lot of relevant hype about them. However, most tutorials go to the extent of only distributing objects. None of the advanced stuff.

Short Story:

What's the best source of learning *Advanced* Geometry Nodes?

(Should this be a community wiki? In case this question is closed, would someone provide a link to where to ask this type of question? "Blender Artists" might be a good idea but I hardly get replies there.)

Comment: As you already found out asking for links to resources about X is considered off topic here, asking directly about X is encouraged though. That is why we have the [Resources for Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15355/resources-for-blender) post. If it is old and outdated we encourage you to update it. See https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2902/what-should-we-do-with-outdated-answers

Comment: checkout the yt channel of erindale, johnny matthews, crossmind studio...

Comment: @Chris noted, thanks for the advice.

Comment: especially erindale is doing really advanced stuff...but explains it very well

Comment: @Chris Yes, it's really good that Erindale can explain so well, because the node trees he published with *Erindale's Toolkit* are anything but self-explanatory :D

Comment: And he often makes huuuuge node trees 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed an opinion-based question.

Therefore, also an opinion-based answer:

In my opinion, one of the best places to learn Geometry Nodes is https://blender.stackexchange.com/.

I've been learning this stuff for three months now, and it's been one of the most intense and exciting learning experiences I've had so far. You'll find a ton of tricky and exciting questions here. Turn to the questions and just try to solve the problem.

And nowhere else can you find so many competent and nice people from whom you can learn so much.

I think there is no greater learning effect.

As additional help you can use the [official documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/) and the [source code](https://github.com/blender/blender) ;-)

Comment: The irony........

Comment: @YousufChaudhry This is just opinion based irony... :D

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking :D